# Can't login to phpMyAdmin on subdomain (no error message)

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-server

First of all, I am aware of all the questions here on SO with very similar titles, but none of the solutions described there worked for me.

My case is a little bit more specific than those questions. I have a domain name pointing to my own server (Ubuntu 17.04, Apache 2.4). On the server, there is a freshly installed instance of phpMyAdmin. When I'm accessing phpMyAdmin's site using domain.com/phpmyadmin it works fine, and I can log in.

What I am trying to achieve is to access phpMyAdmin from a subdomain (ex. php.domain.com). I have the virtual host set up and when I try to access the site, the login page is working just fine, but when I enter my username and password, nothing happens (as opposed to the domain.com/phpmyadmin method, which works just fine), not even an error message.

What I have tried:

- Verify that session.save_path is valid and writeable
- Reinstall phpMyAdmin and MySQL

The following is the apache virtual host config file for the subdomain

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName php.domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/share/phpmyadmin"
    <Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin">
        allow from all
        Options None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    # RewriteEngine on
    # RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =php.domain.com
    # RewriteRule ^ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Why is it that I can't login from the subdomain, but I can from domain.com/phpmyadmin and what shoud I do to make it work?

Comment: You probably need to edit your phpmyadmin/config.inc.php and set `$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri']` since you changed the URL. See https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#basic-settings

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't solve the problem. I noticed when I press enter after entering my credentials, the URL bar changes from php.domain.com to `php.domain.com/index.php?lang=hu&collation_connection=utf8mb4_unicode_ci&token=201735f7c0c1631409b17a89314e303c`. But I'm still stuck at the login page with no error message.

Comment: Funny thing is that I've done this before a couple years ago and it worked. The VirtualHost file was copy-pasted from the original setup. The only thing that's different now is the version of ubuntu (it was 16.04, now 17.04).

Comment: Your vhost has `allow from all` which is an Apache 2.2 config directive, but also has `Require all granted` with is an Apache 2.4 config directive. It's not compatible to use both in one config file. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently all I had to do was delete the cookies in Chrome.